# Flask: How to make all url_for()s create external URLs for one request?

Tags: flask

I'm trying to send one particular page of a large Flask app as an email, so I need to make all url_for() calls generate a full "external" URL for that particular view function. I know how that works, but the page contains many calls to different url_for(), some of which in another module. I don't want to implement extra logic to set the _external argument in all those calls. Rather, I would like to change the behavior of url_for() just for that one request.

This is as far as I've got and, to nobody's surprise, it doesn't work:

```
@blueprint.route('/check/')
def run_checks():
    email = flask.request.args.get('email')
    if email:
        app = flask.current_app
        app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'abc.def'
        print("TEST", flask.url_for('.run_checks')))
```